# M-V-C Fool-proof not working and showing Uncaught error?

Tags: foolproof-validation

I installed Fool-Proof from nuGet, but its not working uncaught errors.

```
Install-Package foolproof -Version 0.9.4518
```

As I installed it, new folder with name `Clients Scripts` gets added in to my project with three libraries: `FoolProof Unobtrusive`, `FoolProof jQuery Validation` and `FoolProof Validation`. Then I create new bundle in `bundle.config` and linked with my shared layout.

```
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("active", true,ErrorMessage = "Code is Required")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
```

It's not displaying validation message. Now, when I checked my console I am getting following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded required js files. Add the following in BundleConfig.js

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mvcfoolproof").Include(
            "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js",
            "~/Client Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/Client Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js",
            "~/Client Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js"));
```

and then include in your View in correct order

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mvcfoolproof")
```